# Why does EntityFramework append a 1 by default in edmx after the database entities?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Why does `EntityFramework` add a **1** by default to a newly created EDMX file?. Say I have a database called **EmployeesDB** , choosing **Add > New ADO.Net Data Entity data model** and choosing this database in the wizard creates multiple files,

including  the **EmployeeDB.Designer.cs** , where we have

```
 public partial class SchoolDBEntities1 : ObjectContext
```

Why is this **1** needed here? It just feels like one of those quick-and-dirty code snippets "Name it like this for now, and give it a proper name latter  things"... But I'm sure there must be a good reason for this

Comment: Perhaps there was already a ShoolDBEntities connection string entry in your app.config from a previous create?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EF uses numbers to resolve name conflicts. Do you already have another class in the project named `SchoolDBEntities`? Maybe an old EDMX file? Or something handwritten? Or maybe a class meant as a partial extension to the `SchoolDBEntities` but where the `partial` keyword is missing?

If you remove the conflicting class, you can rename the newly generated and remove the `1` in the EDMX designer.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by removing the repeated connection strings in web.config.